# Meaning of Makfile options

Tags: linux, shell, makefile

the rule of Makefile below -

SUBDIRS = foo bar baz

```
 subdirs:
         for dir in $(SUBDIRS); do \
           $(MAKE) -C $$dir; \
         done
```

has option -C in it. Can someone tell me as to what the function of this option is?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you check the man page for `make` ?

Comment: it's not simple because if you write "man makefile" nothing append but "man make" will be open your eyes.

Comment: Or even, `make --help`?

Comment: thanks for the information. its much clearer now

Answer (score 0):

```
 -C dir, --directory=dir
            Change to directory dir before reading the makefiles or doing anything else.  If multiple -C options are specified, each is interpreted relative to the previous one: -C  /  -C  etc  is
            equivalent to -C /etc.  This is typically used with recursive invocations of make.
```

Comment: I know that dollar sign $ is used for getting the value of the variables, but what does the double dollar sign $$ do(as seen above- $$dir)?